# Opencv on python3

Tags: pi-3, opencv

I'm trying to do image processing on the pi using a USB webcam,
For which i am using opencv
As a beginner it took me hours to install opencv from this guide: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/18/install-guide-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-jessie-opencv-3/

But i don't know what happened and it got installed only on python 2 not on python 3. Can someone please tell me how to install it on python 3 alone...

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: which distribution of Linux are you running on Raspberry Pi?

use the command line/terminal app to double check which version of Python you are currently running. In the command line type:

python -V

if it is not 3 you can use apt-get. Type:

sudo apt-get install python3

Answer (score 1):

Installing OpenCV is pretty much straightforward process, it just take a lot of time. I googled a lot for the last few months to make a [cheat sheet](https://github.com/Tes3awy/OpenCV-3.1.0-Compiling-on-Raspberry-Pi-2-), and I made one. You can download my cheat sheet and try it out. I don't like Virtual Environment. It's better, though. It isolates your installation from getting later errors when using after installation. I recommend you install OpenCV for Python 2 not 3. If you want for Python 3 just change the appropriate lines in the cheat sheet. I also recommend that you stick to the cheat sheet especially in step 12. Sometime when you use all the processor cores the process fails to continue. You should always use a 2A or 2.5A, 5V Adapter. your Pi 3 peripherals are current hungry, and if current is not sufficient, the Pi shuts down automatically, as it's short-circuit protected.

Don't forget to fork me on GitHub.

Comment: +1, but you should paste that cheat sheet (or at least its essentials) as an answer, in addition to the link to the repo. If the repo moves or gets deleted, the answer will no longer be as helpful as it is now.

Comment: @Bahrom I will add some line, okay (Y)